# jQuery/JS setTimeout() still runs after clearTimeout() called

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have an `input type="number"` and am using the up/down arrows within the field to change the value of the input.  I want to trigger a function after the **final** click/change of the input.

By **final** I mean after the input hasn't been changed for 1000ms (my assumption that the user has now stopped clicking).

I've set up a 1000ms `setTimeout()` that runs the function, but even though I'm calling `clearTimeout()` `.on('change')` of the input, the function runs 1000ms after the **first** change, rather than the last.

I've set up a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tg1xn9L1/) to illustrate what I mean. The `div` with "Hello World!" in it should not appear until after the final click.

If you rapidly click the up arrow on the input (at least once every 999ms) then the `div` should never appear.

I have looked through a lot of other similar questions on here but they're almost all about the scope of the timer variable, which I don't think applies here.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$.on('change')` is only triggered when the input element gains or loses focus, not every time the up arrow input is hit

Comment: ... try on `on('input')` instead. https://jsfiddle.net/mh42wc5z/

Comment: I tryed your Fiddle... And the issue you describe didn't occured. I've been able to click up to 100 without having the *Hello World!* displayed.

Comment: @Hamms: wrong. `Change` is fired on spinner clicks even if the `input` is still in `focus`.

Comment: the precise nature of the change event is browser-dependent; the salient point is that the change event is _not necessarily_ fired for each change to an element's value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: @Hamms: mmm. Ok, so the issue is not occuring in Chrome.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I'm using Chrome v59 and it is occurring for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onchange, is triggered when input loses its focus, try on input.. btw. jquery is not required here.

```
var timeOut;
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("input", function() {
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("bar").style.display = "block";
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered it could be browser differences. I used `.on('input')` and it now works fine. Interestingly, `.on('change')` works as I wanted it to in Firefox, but not in Chrome.